# Homeomorphism between a compact space and non compact space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Can such a thing exist?

I am relatively new to topological spaces but my intuition would be that such a thing cannot exist.
I guess this question could also be asking whether a Hausdorff space can be non-compact.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know what is a homeomorphism?

Comment: No. In general, you can think of a homeomorphism as a type of map between topological spaces which preserves all essential topological information between the two spaces. In this case, two homeomorphic spaces must either share the property of being compact, or not. On the other hand, there are plenty of spaces which are Hausdorff that are not compact. This is a different question entirely.

Comment: Is the real line a Hausdorff space? Is it compact?

Comment: I believe even if it's just a continuous function and not a homeomorphism, the domain would still necessarily be compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous map maps a compact set to a compact set. Then your problem can be solved easily.

Comment: That is if both spaces are Hausdorff.